# Creating a 'git publish' alias, but need to store temporary variable

Tags: git, alias, bash, git-branch

Based on this [article](http://justinfrench.com/notebook/git-aliases-rock) I wanted to create a similar alias (flow described below).  With the author/article's comments disabled, I thought I'd ask it here.  Assuming you are on a 'topic' branch, I'd like to modify the flow to do the following:

- Detect and store the current branch name in $branch (using alias from [here](http://blogs.gnome.org/danni/2011/03/07/useful-git-aliases/))
- Switch back to master branch
- Pull from remote
- Switch back to $branch
- Rebase $branch against master
- Switch back to master
- Merge changes from $branch
- Run wtf

A psuedo alias might be something like (knowing that the references to $branch are most likely wrong):

branch-name = !git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' `git symbolic-ref HEAD`

publish = !git branch-name > $branch && git checkout master && git pull && git checkout $branch && git rebase master && git checkout master && git merge $branch

Is there anyway to pull this off?  I've no idea how to store/use the $branch variable (note, coming from a windows/c#/VSS background so pretty green in git still).

Final note, I am using git from within a Windows Powershell console window.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Git checkout -
```

will checkout the previous branch, so you don't need to store it.

When you do need it, you can get it from .git/HEAD

Hope this helps

Comment: So you are saying `publish = !git checkout master && git pull && git checkout - && git rebase master && git checkout master && git merge -` would work?

Comment: so it all worked until the git merge -.  That failed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't `merge -`. the `-` only works with `cd` and `git checkout`. It changes directory to the previous one and checks out the previous branch respectively.

Comment: you need to do `git merge head@{1}`. `head@{1}` means the 1st place in history of where head pointed to. This is your other branch.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  `checkin = !git reset --soft master && git commit -a && git checkout master && git pull && git checkout - && git pull --rebase . master && git checkout master && git merge head@{1}`